# Javascript Get File Interface Extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, file

Is there a library to get file extension for File Type in JS or Typescript? We are currently doing this code:

```
  if (files[0].name.slice(-4) !== '.csv') {
    errorMessages.push('File must be in CSV format.');
  }
```

**Resource File Interface:**

```
/** Provides information about files and allows JavaScript in a web page to access their content. */
interface File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModified: number;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly webkitRelativePath: string;
}

declare var File: {
    prototype: File;
    new(fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag): File;
};
```

Comment: Is this code executing in the browser? Or in Node or Deno?

Comment: hi @AlexanderNied its in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the file extends blob you can get the mime-type by doing `file.type(`) then you check if it's equal to "text/csv". Also the package `mime-types` is handy.